# Android Studio - Gradle KeyStore Signing config

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, keystore

I am compiling a gradle project in Android Studio and i am getting following issue.

Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':Proj:packageDebug'.

> File '/Users/SB/proj /~/debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

Please Help me out.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is not able to locate your debug keystore.

As the error points out, you need to place your debug.keystore file at the path specified against "storeFile" in your build.gradle.

Comment: What path should that be? Where is the debug keystore, can someone share?

Comment: the debug keystore is usually under directory ~/.android in your root folder. Its created automatically by the IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio)